# Perl.Average value for each array of matrix

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, matrix

I created a function, which generates a random matrix.

```
sub gen {
    my $x = int(rand($_[0]-1)+1);
    my $y = int(rand($_[1]-1)+1);
    my $matrix = [ map [ map int(rand($_[2]-1)+1), 1..$x ], 1..$y ];
    return $matrix;
}

my $array_ref = $gen(5,10,5);
```

**How could  i get the average value for each array of matrix?
And if possible without regular expressions.**

I haven't understand completely openings of references for arrays yet, but this is my attempt. I was trying to get all values and divide it by @_ which get scalar number of elements in array:

```
sub func{
    my $sum;
    my @avg;
    my $avg;
    foreach (@$array_ref) {
        $sum += $_;
        $avg = $sum/@_;
    }
    push (@avg, $avg);
}
```

Comment: You've stated your goal but haven't demonstrated any attempt to do it yourself. (Technically, you haven't even asked a question.)

Comment: that is all true, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by average you want sum divided by number of elements,

```
use List::Util qw(sum);

for my $r (@$array_ref) {

  printf("%.2f\n",  sum(@$r)/@$r);
}
```

without modules,

```
sub sum {
  my $n = 0;
  $n += $_ for @_;
  return $n;
}

for my $r (@$array_ref) {

  printf("%.2f\n",  sum(@$r)/@$r);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can i do that without regexp?

Comment: @sliddy it is not regex, but you always can `print sum(@$r)/@$r;`

Comment: Oh y right, but can i do that without using any module?

Comment: @sliddy it is already installed, a core-module. Check update.